# Make a book index out of "gran1>parent1>child1; gran1>parent1>child2" sort of thing with bash with sed or awk or whatever

Tags: bash, awk, sed, command-line

sorry for the title but I don't know how to express in words the following structure that I parsed from an html:

```
title1 &gt; SubTitle1 &gt; SubSubTitle1
title1 &gt; SubTitle1 &gt; SubSubTitleTwo
title1 &gt; SubTitle1 &gt; SubSubTitleIII
title1 &gt; SubTitle1 &gt; SubSubTitleDelta
title1 &gt; SubTitleII &gt; DifferentSubSubTitle1
title1 &gt; SubTitleII &gt; DifferentSubSubTitleTwo
titleBeta &gt; SubTitleGamma &gt; AnotherSubSubTitle1
titleBeta &gt; SubTitleGamma &gt; AnotherSubSubTitleTwo
```

Each title (of different lengths) has many subtitles (of different lengths) in a number different from other titles. This property is valid also for the relation (subtitle, subsubtitle). Titles of any kind may have spaces inside them.

I want to build a book index like

```
title1
  SubTitle1
    SubSubTitle1
    SubSubTitleTwo
    SubSubTitleIII
    SubSubTitleDelta
  SubTitleII
    DifferentSubSubTitle1
    DifferentSubSubTitleTwo
titleBeta
  SubTitleGamma
    AnotherSubSubTitle1
    AnotherSubSubTitleTwo
```

How can I do that with bash with sed or awk or other common command line tools?

BTW, if anyone knows how to call these structures in words I can modify the title of the question.

Thanks,
Luca

Comment: No spaces? Then we don't even need the `sep` character.

Comment: So far I managed to "verticalize" of the thing but keeping all the duplicates like
title1 \n   SubTitle1 \n     SubSubTitle1 \n title1 \n   SubTitle1 \n     SubSubTitleTwo (with an actual newline in place of \n, and spaces in the right place that I can't reproduce in a comment)

Comment: No spaces. I thought It could be done and that it's a problem that may recur.

Comment: Sorry guys I realized I wrote "w/o" but I intended "with". Now I understand the irony of @MarkAdelsberger. :D

Comment: @MarkAdelsberger, I'm actually not sure I agree with that comparison. Bash has a very rich set of [string manipulation tools](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/100) built-in -- and using external commands inappropriately is much of why bash has its reputation for extremely bad performance.

Comment: (Bash *is* slow, to be sure, but but it's much slower when one's spinning up a pipeline inside of a tight inner loop; similarly, when scripts use only builtin syntax, the shell itself can be improved to optimize their performance -- but the cost of `fork()`ing and `exec()`ing to start an external command is fixed, no matter how the shell improves).

Answer (score 3):

You can use `awk` like this :

```
awk '{
        if (title != $1){
            print $1
            title = $1
        }
        if (subtitle != $3){
            print "  "$3
            subtitle = $3
        }
        if (subsubtitle != $5){
            print "    "$5
            subsubtitle = $5
        }
     }' test.txt
```

It stores your 3 types, print the value if it detects changes. You can replace spaces for tabs if needed

Comment: Other than the question asking explicitly for pure bash without any external tools (explicitly including awk), this is ideal.

Comment: Sorry I mistyped w/o in place of "with".

Comment: I didn't mention that titles has spaces inside them. It's been a while since I last used awk (and I know very little about it). I tried this code but it seem to consider the space a field sparator. Another thing I didn't mention is that the list is quite long.

Comment: In the future, do try to make your test data comprehensive enough that something that passes it answers your question.

Comment: Sorry, I tried my best to be clear but I realized I didn't mention titles have spaces inside them only after reading the answers.

Comment: Anyway I agree that test data should really be test data of the actual problem, spaces included. Next time, I'll do better.

Answer (score 3):

another `awk` for unlimited levels

```
$ awk -F' +&gt; +' 'BEGIN {tabs="\0\t\t\t\t\t"}
                          {for(i=1;i<=NF;i++) 
                             if($i!=p[i]) printf "%s\n",substr(tabs,1,i) $i;
                           split($0,p)} ' file

title1
        SubTitle1
                SubSubTitle1
                SubSubTitleTwo
                SubSubTitleIII
                SubSubTitleDelta
        SubTitleII
                DifferentSubSubTitle1
                DifferentSubSubTitleTwo
titleBeta
        SubTitleGamma
                AnotherSubSubTitle1
                AnotherSubSubTitleTwo
```

indentation is with tabs, but can be done with spaces easily

```
$ awk -F' +&gt; +' '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++)
                       if($i!=p[i]) printf "%" 4*(i-1) "s%s\n","", $i;
                     split($0,p)} ' file

title1
    SubTitle1
        SubSubTitle1
        SubSubTitleTwo
        SubSubTitleIII
        SubSubTitleDelta
    SubTitleII
        DifferentSubSubTitle1
        DifferentSubSubTitleTwo
titleBeta
    SubTitleGamma
        AnotherSubSubTitle1
        AnotherSubSubTitleTwo
```

Comment: Thanks. The first awk command don't indent the subtitles and subsubtitles. I know very little of awk so I can't say what's wrong at first glance. The second awk works perfectly.

Answer (score 2):

Porting karafka's answer, with added support for titles with spaces:

```
sep=$'\t' # this should be a character that can't exist in a title
prior_pieces=( )
while IFS= read -r line; do
  line=${line//&gt;/$sep}
  IFS=$sep read -r -a pieces <<<"$line"
  for idx in "${!pieces[@]}"; do
    if [[ ${prior_pieces[$idx]} != ${pieces[$idx]} ]]; then
      printf '%*s%s\n' "$(( 2 * idx ))" "" "${pieces[$idx]}"
      prior_pieces[$idx]=${pieces[$idx]}
    fi
  done
done
```